# soapUI export code to python

Tags: python-3.x, soap, python-requests, soapui

Hola estoy intentando exportar un request hecho en soapUI a mi programa en python, basicamente he copiado y pegado el request que uso en soapIU  en mi codigo utilizando la libreria "requests" correctamente pero en SoapUI hay unas "Request Properties" que no sé como exportar a código, aqui adjunto la imagen, estas propiedades sale en la esquina inferior derecha del programa y es donde uno coloca el nombre de usuario y contraseña entre otros.

[image: Request Properties]

Adjunto mi código aquí, omitiendo el body enviado

```
def getInfoSoap():
import requests
url = "http://10.0.0.133:13080/SM/7/ws"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
#headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml','Username':'Falcon'}
body = "aqui va el xml"
response = requests.post(url, data=body,
                        # headers=headers,
                         verify=False)
print(str(response.content))
```

el response:

```
b'<HTML><BODY>Not Authorized</BODY></HTML>'
```

ayuda por favor